# Why does the band gap decrease when the thickness of the material increases?

Tags: solid-state-physics

Thin films of material (monolayers, etc) tend to have higher band gaps than their bulk materials. This is true for a wide range of materials. What is the reason? Is it due to the fact that there is less energy splitting in thin films than in bulk?

Answer (score 3):

This is a general property of square potential wells. De broglie wavelength of the ground state is approximatly twice the well width. For this reason wider wells have smaller wave-numbers ($k=\frac{2 \pi}{\lambda}$) of the groundstate. Hence the lower energy of the ground state (and others) (since $E=\frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2 m}$).

Comment: But this effect works in the other direction, it increases the band gap of confined nanostructures https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_well

Comment: @user_na I'm not sure what you're saying. The lower energies I meant were those of the bulk/wider wells. See the example here (especially how the energy depends on the inverse of the square of the potential well width) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well#Finding_wavefunctions_for_the_bound_state

Comment: you are right, I misread your answer @Alexander . Maybe it's a good idea to insert the quantum confinement image from the wiki link from my post, because it illustrates the answer very well.

Comment: I think that the reasoning is reasonable. However, I am not sure how accurate it is, considering that electrons in semiconducotors, metals, etc are not exactly particles in a box. It is true that they can be described as being nearly free electrons. But I am not so sure about the boundary conditions

Comment: Also, isn't the band gap the difference between energy levels? Wouldn't both the Conduction Band and Valence Band also decrease in energy?

Comment: Band gap is the energy difference between "upper" well's and "lower" well's ground states, as shown here http://ldselection.com/tutorial/wp-content/uploads/fig1.5.1.png

Comment: The parts oft the wavefunction which are confined are in a good approximation particles in a box. When looking at real materials things can also be the other way around. This is because thin Films tend to grow with the lattice constant oft the substrate where thicker films are more likely to relax some of the strain.

Answer (score 0):

When the thickness of material decrease .. there is a quantum effect is present there, which called "the quantum confinement " which limited of movement of electrons and given as a consequence the quantum effects such as the quantization of their energy and momentum.
these things can increase the band gap since it depends immediately on the movement of electrons

Comment: I'm confused as to how the band gap depends on the movement of electrons.